# How to get count of postitive and negative numbers per ID?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, window-functions

I'd like to get a count of negative values and positive values for each id.

[Sample Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db410)

`ID=1 has 2 positive and 0 negative transactions. etc.`

```
 with trans_detail as 
 (
 select 1 as trans_id, 100 as trans_amount  from dual union all
 select 1 as trans_id, 200 as trans_amount  from dual union all
 select 2 as trans_id, -100 as trans_amount  from dual union all
 select 2 as trans_id, -300 as trans_amount  from dual union all
 select 3 as trans_id, 400 as trans_amount   from dual union all
 select 3 as trans_id, -500 as trans_amount  from dual
 )

 select trans_id,
       count(*) over (partition by trans_id) as pos_count,
       count(*) over (partition by trans_id) as neg_count        
from trans_detail
where trans_amount > 0
UNION
select trans_id,
       count(*) over (partition by trans_id) as pos_count,
       count(*) over (partition by trans_id) as neg_count        
from trans_detail
where trans_amount < 0;
```

Desired Result:

```
 ID   POS_COUNT   NEG_COUNT
---- ----------- -----------
 1    2           0 
 2    0           2
 3    1           1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Count 1 each time you see a positive or negative amount and sum that up.

```
select trans_id,
sum(case when trans_amount >=0 then 1 else 0 end) as pos_amt,
sum(case when trans_amount < 0 then 1 else 0 end) as neg_amt
from trans_detail
group by trans_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db410/12

Answer (score 1):

```
select trans_id, 
nvl(sum(case when trans_amount < 0 then 1 end),0) as neg,
nvl(sum(case when trans_amount > 0 then 1 end),0) as pos
from trans_detail
group by trans_id
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db410/15

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional count:

```
with trans_detail as 
 (
 select 1 as trans_id, 100 as trans_amount  from dual union all
 select 1 as trans_id, 200 as trans_amount  from dual union all
 select 2 as trans_id, -100 as trans_amount  from dual union all
 select 2 as trans_id, -300 as trans_amount  from dual union all
 select 3 as trans_id, 400 as trans_amount   from dual union all
 select 3 as trans_id, -500 as trans_amount  from dual
 )
select trans_id,
       count(case when trans_amount >= 0 then trans_id end) as pos_count,
       count(case when trans_amount < 0 then trans_id end) as neg_count        
from trans_detail
group by trans_id
order by trans_id;

  TRANS_ID  POS_COUNT  NEG_COUNT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          0
         2          0          2
         3          1          1
```

Count ignores null values, so the implicit null 'else' to each case means those rows aren't counted. You can add `else null` if you prefer but it just makes it a bit longer. (I've included zero as 'positive' but you may want to ignore it completely as in your question; in which case just revert to `> 0`).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db410/17)

You could also use [the `sign` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions164.htm), either in a case or a decode:

```
select trans_id,
       count(decode(sign(trans_amount), 1, trans_id)) as pos_count,
       count(decode(sign(trans_amount), -1, trans_id)) as neg_count        
from trans_detail
group by trans_id
order by trans_id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db410/29); this ignores zero but you could include it in either decode if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select trans_id,
       Sum(case when trans_amount>=0 then 1 else 0 end) as pos_count,
       Sum(case when trans_amount<0 then 1 else 0 end) as neg_count,
from trans_detail
group by trans_id
```